# unable to copy animation

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

@blender we have imported walking animation from Mixamo(.fbx) ---- source

We imported rigged animation(.glb) avatar ----Target

We need to replace the target animation with source animation

[image]
Initially i deleted all the existing animation of Target and Reposed it to A-Pose.
Then we tried with this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdD9odG_CQs  but it didnt work out.
It is not throwing any error but animations are not copied

pls suggest the sol for this…

Comment: the armature needs to have bones that have the same names as the original armature, is it the case?